# How to describe a building set which is like LEGO without using the "LEGO" word?

Tags: shopping, clone-brands, terminology

We are sellers of building toys like LEGO online. But their website does not allow using the word "LEGO" directly to describe the products. Are there any other words that could describe the building sets like LEGO? It seems that LEGO is the representative of all kinds of building sets.

Answer (score 20):

The usual phrases I've seen include some mixture of the following:

- Universal interlocking bricks
- Modular building system
- Plastic construction toy blocks

and so on...

But don't forget adding "Compatible with leading brands" if it is indeed the case :)

Comment: I would use a mix of the above - modular plastic building blocks.

Comment: Often "bricks" is used instead of "building blocks".

Comment: @Raidri Thanks, edited!

Comment: "Universal plastic interocking modular construction building toy brick blocks system" seems like something I would see on ebay or Wish

Answer (score 8):

The answer can be closer than you think. Quoting from the Bricks [help](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help) page:

> Bricks is a question and answer site for LEGO and **building block** enthusiasts.

Comment: Living in China, home to a lot of LEGO clones, the wording "blocks" is indeed the most popular here in shops and pre-schools.

Answer (score 5):

...actually it’s a highly sophisticated interlocking brick system

source [Lego Movie Quotes on WIkipedia](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Lego_Movie)

Answer (score 4):

I have seen the sentence "Compatible." in product descriptions. When you are selling interlocking plastic toys, you can assume that everyone knows what this means.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this items ([first](https://www.maerklin.de/en/products/details/article/44734/) and [second](https://www.lgb.de/produkte/details/article/94063)) and their descriptions: `clip-on blocks` and `Building Block` respectivly.